# What is the purpose of the "window" icon in the menu bar in Windows 8 on hover?

Tags: windows-8

What is this icon in the menu bar when I hover? I can't click on it. It appears to do nothing.
[image]

Comment: I can't seem to find that on mine - it might belong to a addon

Comment: Looking at the icon it reminds me of multi-desktop management systems, does anything happen when you click on it?

Comment: No, nothing happens when I click on it

Comment: Is that title bar for internet explorer?

Comment: @Ben Plont It looks like an Explorer window opened to the Downloads folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an icon for [Dell PremierColor](http://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/04/campaigns/dell-ultrasharpmonitor_color). You can use that icon to send a window to another screen, if you have multiple monitors connected.